# Adding dataframe column to numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For a regression, I would like to add a dataframe column to a numpy.array which contains dummy variables.

Currently, the array looks like this:

```
[[0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]]
```

I would like to add the dataframe column values (which has 7 rows in this example) so that 5 values are inside the square brackets (the one from the dataframe column and four dummy variables).

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data? Pandas is backed by numpy so everything under the hood is already numpy and you should be able to treat your dataframe as an array for all intents and purposes.

Comment: my current code looks like this:
for product in df_train.columns[1:]:   
    x = pd.get_dummies(x[product])    
    x_past = np.array(x.values)

and I would like to add a dataframe column to the array as explained above. However, if I simply append it, the array does not have the same structure as above.

Comment: Please don't put code in comments where it is unformatted and difficult to read. Click `edit` under your question and put the code there. Thank you.

Comment: Also, just create a dummy pandas frame, similar to your Numpy array, and then show the result you want - miles easier

Answer (score 1):

You could use your numpy array to create a dataframe:

```
array=np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 0]])
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data=array)
```

and then add your column to it like this:

```
new_dataframe['4'] = your_dataframe['column_name']
```